# seperation of strings with special characters

Tags: ios, data-structures

I am making a calculator and unable to seperate the input string in corrosponding to operands.
For example : 2*5 - 6 +8/2. I want an array with components 2, 5, 6, 8, 2 so that I can store the oprators also and then sort accordingly. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *str=@"2*5 - 6 +8/2";  // assume that this is your str

// here remove the white space  
str =[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];  
// here remove the all special characters in NSString
NSCharacterSet *noneedstr = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*/-+."];
str = [[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: noneedstr] componentsJoinedByString:@","];
 NSLog(@"the str=-=%@",str);
```

the out put is

```
 the str=-=2,5,6,8,2
```

Comment: It is useful to understand and getthe reult

Comment: if my answer is fine give the up vote ,it is useful for others in future

Comment: Brother i am not seeing any tick mark.No tick mark here.

Comment: k bro have a nice day ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method, componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:.

```
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*-+/"];
NSArray *numbers = [text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:set];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get arrays of the operands and operators like so. This assumes the expression is valid, base 10, begins and ends with operands, etc. The expression would then be operands[0], operators[0], operands[1], operators[1], and so on.

```
NSString *expression = @"2*5 - 6 +8/2";

// Could use a custom character set as well, or -whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet
NSCharacterSet *whitespaceCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSArray *nonWhitespaceComponents = [expression componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmedExpression = [nonWhitespaceComponents componentsJoinedByString:@""];

// To get an array of the operands:
NSCharacterSet *operatorCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"+-/*"];
NSArray *operands = [trimmedExpression componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:operatorCharacterSet];

// To get the array of operators:
NSCharacterSet *baseTenCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
NSArray *operators = [trimmedExpression componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:baseTenCharacterSet];
// Since expression should begin and end with operands, first and last strings will be empty
NSMutableArray *mutableOperators = [operators mutableCopy];
[mutableOperators removeObject:@""];
operators = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutableOperators];

NSLog(@"%@", operands);
NSLog(@"%@", operators);
```